# Ubuntu Phone App Development Clarification

Tags: application-development, phone, qt-creator, qt5

I attempting to follow the [Ubuntu Phone App development tutorial to make a Currency Converter](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/), and I am simply unable to complete the tutorial. I have installed all of the latest QT/Phone related content available from the PPA's in the guide. I press Ctrl+n to open a new project, but I am lost as soon as I reach this window:

[image]

The guide is not clear as to what to do at this window. My guess is that the QT Creator provided by the PPA has been updated/changed slightly since this guide was made 3 months ago.

Can someone clarify what to do next so I can complete the Currency Converter tutorial? Or maybe to make a picture guide from start to finish in your answer? Thank you!

Comment: From the guide, `Select the Projects > Application > Qt Quick UI template and click Choose…`. It seems to be renamed to Qt Quick 1 UI, can you try it ?

Comment: I click on Projects, in the left side pane, and I see nowhere Application. Where should I find it?

Comment: Here http://i.imgur.com/69ghaTa.png

Comment: Ok, I did that, made the project, added the code to the project, 
but when I try running it using Ctrl+r I get this message:Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
file:///home/dominic/System/QT Apps/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml:2:1: module "Ubuntu.Components" is not installed 
     import Ubuntu.Components 0.1 
     ^